# Can't get Phonegap app to launch on android Samsung Galaxy s6

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I have an app that I have previously released on the Google Play store and also iTunes however we have not made a new version for about 6 months.  With the previous version I never had any issue installing on Android devices.  My method was simple, just email the apk to myself, click on it and it would load every time.  Now, that method is not working.  The app installs but when it opens i just get a message saying "Unfortunately,  has stopped.

After much research and many failed attempts I finally figured out how to install via the command line using this command:

```
phonegap run android --device --verbose
```

which at least gives me a little more info than i had before which was nothing.  The following is the entire output of that command (which simply hangs for a few minutes before exiting:

```
No scripts found for hook "before_run".


No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".


Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project


Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.

Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.

PlatformApi successfully found for platform android


Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project


Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform


No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...


Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml


Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml


Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/android/platform_www] to platforms/android/assets/www


Wrote out android application name "CraftsmanRepublic" to /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml


android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (1.3.5): 10305


Wrote out Android package name "com.m2.velexo" to /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/src/com/m2/velexo/MainActivity.java


Found extra default icon: www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png (ignoring in favor of www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png)

Found extra default icon: www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png (ignoring in favor of www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png)

Found extra default icon: www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png (ignoring in favor of www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png)
Found extra default icon: www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png (ignoring in favor of www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png)

Found extra default icon: www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png (ignoring in favor of www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png)

Found extra default icon: www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png (ignoring in favor of www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png)

Found extra default icon: www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png (ignoring in favor of www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png)


Found extra default icon: www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png (ignoring in favor of www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png)

Updating icons at platforms/android/res


Updating splash screens at platforms/android/res


This app does not have additional resource files defined


Prepared android project successfully


Executing script found in hooks directory for hook "after_prepare": hooks/after_prepare/node_modules


Skipped directory "/Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/hooks/after_prepare/node_modules" within hook directory

Executing script found in hooks directory for hook "after_prepare": hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js


Running command: /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile


TypeError: _.keyBy is not a function

TypeError: Cannot read property 'permissions' of undefined

TypeError: _.keyBy is not a function

Command finished with error code 0: /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile


Running command: /usr/libexec/java_home 


Command finished with error code 0: /usr/libexec/java_home 


ANDROID_HOME=/Users/dallascaley/Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Running command: /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true


The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.


    at build_648tt8e3eddnib21cv5hmdpsm.run(/Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/build.gradle:139)


The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.


The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.


:preBuild

UP-TO-DATE

:preDebugBuild

UP-TO-DATE

:checkDebugManifest


:preReleaseBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
 UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest


:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies


:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:bundleDebug

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest


:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies


:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders

UP-TO-DATE


:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:bundleRelease
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132340Library
 UP-TO-DATE


:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
 UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1104Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1104Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1104Library

UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1104Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1104Library
 UP-TO-DATE
:prepareMeLeolinShortcutBadger1119Library
 UP-TO-DATE

:prepareOrgApacheCordovaCordovaLib622DebugLibrary
 UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies


:compileDebugAidl

UP-TO-DATE

:compileDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues

UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:mergeDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:processDebugManifest

UP-TO-DATE

:processDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources 
UP-TO-DATE

:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
 UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
 UP-TO-DATE

:compileDebugNdk
 UP-TO-DATE

:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

:mergeDebugShaders
 UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugShaders
 UP-TO-DATE

:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

:mergeDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE

:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

UP-TO-DATE
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE

:processDebugJavaRes

UP-TO-DATE

:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

UP-TO-DATE


:validateSigningDebug


:packageDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE

:cdvBuildDebug

UP-TO-DATE



BUILD SUCCESSFUL


Total time: 1.802 secs

Command finished with error code 0: /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true


Built the following apk(s): 
    /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk


No scripts found for hook "before_deploy".


ANDROID_HOME=/Users/dallascaley/Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home

Running command: adb devices


Command finished with error code 0: adb devices


Running adb shell command "cat /proc/cpuinfo" on target 1215fc3807890504...

Running command: adb -s 1215fc3807890504 shell cat /proc/cpuinfo

Command finished with error code 0: adb -s,1215fc3807890504,shell,cat,/proc/cpuinfo


Skipping build...


Built the following apk(s): 
    /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk


Using apk: /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Package name: com.m2.velexo

Installing apk /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk on target 1215fc3807890504...

Running command: adb -s 1215fc3807890504 install -r /Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Command finished with error code 0: adb -s,1215fc3807890504,install,-r,/Users/dallascaley/Sites/scotch-box/velexo-mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Running adb shell command "input keyevent 82" on target 1215fc3807890504...


Running command: adb -s 1215fc3807890504 shell input keyevent 82

Command finished with error code 0: adb -s,1215fc3807890504,shell,input,keyevent,82


Starting application "com.m2.velexo/.MainActivity" on target 1215fc3807890504...


Running adb shell command "am start -W -a android.intent.action.MAIN -ncom.m2.velexo/.MainActivity" on target 1215fc3807890504...
Running command: adb -s 1215fc3807890504 shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.MAIN -ncom.m2.velexo/.MainActivity
```

At this point the script hangs for about 5 minutes, and then displays the following before exiting:

```
Command finished with error code 0: adb -s,1215fc3807890504,shell,am,start,-W,-a,android.intent.action.MAIN,-ncom.m2.velexo/.MainActivity

LAUNCH SUCCESS

No scripts found for hook "after_run".


[phonegap] completed 'cordova run android --device --verbose --no-telemetry'
```

Comment: Note, I just noticed the TypeError: _.keyBy is not a function errors and fixed both of them by copying over the lodash folder from my node_modules into the node_modules folder in hooks/after_prepare.  This did not however fix the 'Cannot read property 'permissions' of undefined error which i can't seem to locate the source of...

Comment: And now i have fixe the: Cannot read property of 'permissions' error which was caused when the update_platform_config function tried to process the "browser" platform.  fixed by removing the browser platform. not sure what i needed it for anyway.  Still the app will not load however. and i see no other obvious errors in the log.

Comment: try using `adb logcat` to monitor the android logs -- this should give you the explicit error thats causing the app to crash

Comment: I did try to do that but I gave up.  There was also some issue with accessing the phone via usb which i think was preventing me from getting log info.  I fixed that by uninstalling the samsung smartlink app.  In the end i could not wait for an answer to this so i went a completely different route (explained in my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have no idea what the original problem was but I did get my app to load finally.  The way I did it was by creating a brand new hello world app and slowly copying all the code from my old app into it while manually adding the plugins and fixing issues along the way.

Comment: It happened to me. When things get too complicated, they crash.